# Amazon CORS-enabled api returns no 'Access-Control_allow_Origin' header

Tags: ajax, cors, aws-api-gateway

After setting up Amazon API Gateway CORS as instructed, I still get the following error when send an Ajax POST request.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://-------.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/--------. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://------.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I'm using Amazon S3 to host the website, which does not support web script so I can't use python or php to fix this.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Just want to make sure, is your API returning a 2xx response? There is a known limitation with API Gateway that 4xx or 5xx error codes won't return the necessary CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're using Lambda-proxy integration and your Lambda is not returning those headers? If that's the case, you have to add those headers yourself.

This is how I use to create the response that I return using `callback(null, response)`.

```
function createResponse(statusCode, body) {
    const headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }

    return {
        headers,
        statusCode,
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined,
    }
}
```